# When to load data from API and render screen

Tags: reactjs

I seem to run into an issue while learning react. I call an Api, which returns a complex object, and attempt to render my screen based on that data.

```
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Constructor of MyComponent..");

        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.state = {data: {}}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const request = {
            method: 'GET',
            URL: `${Server.ApiURL}/api/data`
        };
        console.log('Calling fetch....');

        fetchData(request)
        .then((data) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            console.log("Data recieved!", data);
             this.setState(
                         { data: data });
        });
    }
```

And then I try render my scree:

```
 render() {
        {if (this.isLoading) return (<div>Loading...</div>)}
        return (
            <div className="row" style={containerStyle}>
                <div className="col-sm-4">
                     <EditBox  required={true}  label="Email Address" value={this.state.email}     onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
                     <Dropdown required={true}  label="Client Type" value={this.state.clientTypeId}   onChange={this.handleClientTypeChange} data={this.state.clientTypes}/>
...
```

EditBox is a container that renders an edit box, and DropDwon is a component, that does an Array.map though the 'data' prop.

However, when I call the setstate, I am getting:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application.

This is maybe only a warning, but ... how should I be getting the data and loading it?

Also, will my 'data' noad be populated with the json, which I can then reference later? For example, my reply:

> {id: 1, name: "Name Testing", clientTypes: [{id:1, displayName: "Test"}] ...}

Can I reference:

```
this.state.name
```

Comment: Could you show the complete component?

Comment: You shouldn't mix component's properties and component's state values. Your `loading` property should be in the state along with the data, because the `loading` technically isn't done until the data has been loaded into the state. Setting component properties (i.e. `this.foo = 'bar'`) is synchronous, but state updates via `setState()` are asynchronous. It's best not to mix their logic if they are related. Also, with this code at the top of render: `{if (this.isLoading) return (<div>Loading...</div>)}` I'm not sure why you put curly braces around it, they aren't needed

Comment: Thanks @jayce444 - I’ll move the isLoading into state. I’ve added some more code to show what I do.  And as for the curly braces - I have no idea either. :) I thought it was required. Will remove.